# Apache Spark : How to add default and specific dependency?

Tags: apache-spark, dependencies

My spark-defaults.conf :

```
#a package I need everytime
spark.jars.packages org.influxdb:influxdb-java:2.14
```

When I launch a job :

```
spark-shell --master yarn --num-executors 6 --packages "a random package that I need only for this job specifically"
```

I get this error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/influxdb/InfluxDBFactory
  at ch.cern.sparkmeasure.InfluxDBSink.<init>(influxdbsink.scala:53)
  at ch.cern.sparkmeasure.InfluxDBSinkExtended.<init>(influxdbsink.scala:232)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$loadExtensions$1.apply(Utils.scala:2688)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$loadExtensions$1.apply(Utils.scala:2680)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.loadExtensions(Utils.scala:2680)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$setupAndStartListenerBus$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:2387)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$setupAndStartListenerBus$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:2386)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.setupAndStartListenerBus(SparkContext.scala:2386)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:555)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:935)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:926)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
  at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:106)
  ... 62 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.influxdb.InfluxDBFactory
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  ... 88 more
```

I think --packages overriding packages in spark-default.conf so I get this error

I don't want to include every time influxdb packages.

I want to have fixe packages in spark-default.conf and dynamic package when I launch a job with --packages but it seems incompatible.

Any idea ?

Comment: Are you using maven, sbt or something else ?

Comment: spark-submit -> sbt 
nothing whith spark-shell 
the behaviour is the same

Answer (score 0):

That class is indeed part of influxdb-java, so you shouldn't be getting that error. Especially if your code isn't even trying to use Influx packages

However, if you have packages specific to a certain application, you should actually package them as *part of that application*. Then others will be able to run it as well and not remember the specific invocation of the spark submit options

If you are using a build system for your code, look into creating an uber jar

I'm not familiar with the semantics of spark-defaults or if it's overridden, but if you do have packages that always need to be part of Spark applications, you should just download the JARs directly into the Spark workers classpaths, not make applications download them every time

Comment: Add JARs directly into the Spark classpaths seems a good idea but Influxdb-java come with many dependency. I don't want to manage Influxdb-java dependency everytime that a need to change the version. --packages do the job for me.
Another idea is to create a FAT JARs file or create an VAR ENV (with all packages that spark needs to start in my case).
For instance I choose the second choice, now user need to : spark-submit --package $VARENV

PS : I confirm that --packages overridden spark default in spark-default.conf